# storing/appending a list of values as a property of a relationship in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to store the metadata of my application in Neo4j.

So each time the application is successful, I am trying to store the count of rows processed in that batch
appended into the property of the relationship.

So, if in first batch, my application processes 30k rows, the graph database should look like this:

```
MERGE (N:Entity {name : "Cassandra"})-[:Success{rows:30000}]->(N:Entity{name:"MySQL"})
```

Now in the second batch if my application processes 20k rows, the database should APPEND 20000 in the rows property of Success edge. Something of this sort :

```
MERGE (N:Entity {name : "Cassandra"})-[:Success{rows.APPEND(20000)}]->(N:Entity{name:"MySQL"})
```

so the output would look like this : [30000, 20000].

Is it even possible doing that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you're looking for?

```
MERGE (n1:Entity {name : "Cassandra"})-[s:Success]->(n2:Entity{name:"MySQL"})
SET s.rows = coalesce(s.rows, []) + 20000
```

Comment: your solution is adding up the new row number with the existing one, 30k + 20k. But what I am looking for is a way to see both the row numbers separately that is in a list i.e. [30000, 20000]

Comment: I understand. I edited my first answer to get a list instead of a sum. If your variable is a list, then the + appends to the list.
````WITH [30000] AS oldList
RETURN oldList + 20000 AS newList````

Comment: If you run my sample code twice times, s.rows = [2000,2000], not 40000.